# Validar data menor que a data atual

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa, jsp

A minha dúvida é a seguinte. Tenho um formulário em JSP para o cadastro de alunos com vários atributos, um deles é a data de nascimento. Até então eu estava cadastrando a data apenas validando o formato (dd/MM/yyyy) e com annotations. Mas agora, eu preciso de fato validar a data de um modo que o usuário não possa cadastrar uma data posterior a data de hoje e nenhuma das ideias que tive e implementei na JPA funcionou. Alguém sabe uma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Você poderia demonstrar onde você está fazendo a validação e o que deve acontecer se a validação não for bem sucedida? Em especial, saber se a validação é feita no JSP, javascript, servlet, taglib, spring, CDI ou o que for. O Reginaldo Rigo postou uma resposta que mostra como comparar datas, mas sem você deixar claro qual é o lugar onde você faz a validação, qual annotation você usa onde, fica difícil dar uma resposta mais completa que isso.

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
public static boolean comparaDatas(String psDate1, String psDate2) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(psDate1);
        Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(psDate2);
        if(date2.after(date1)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você pode substituir o `if(date2.after(date1)) { return true; } else { return false; }` por apenas `return date2.after(date1);`

Comment: Sim. Com certeza.